# Getting error in MVC5 and EF View Scaffolding with DbContext selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have my MVC project in one assembly and the Data Project which Contains the DbContext Class in another assembly with Entity/Model class being another in the same solution.

Whenever I try to create a View with Scaffolding with the DbContext menu selecting the DbContext inherited class I get this run time error :

> There was a problem running the selected code generator "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Controller Class :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

DbContext Class :

```
public class BlogDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BlogCatagory> BlogCatagories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BlogType> BlogTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public BlogDbContext() :base("name=MVPDB")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Now suppose, I want to create a View for the Login with Edit and selected the DbContext class I get a window popping up saying :

> There was a problem running the selected code generator "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: can share screenshot of error window which you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because of the Entity Model.

I would recommend you to delete and recreate the Entity Data Model **against which you are creating this View**

- Recreate it
- Rebuild The Solution
- Try Re-Creating the View

hope it helps.